# Python regular expression for .properties file

Tags: python, regex

I have a properties file from which I need to extract some specific properties line:

My Properties File contents are:

```
datahelper.SecLegalAgreementParty.queryAttributes = type=DataProcessorHelper, contextType=REFERENCE, dataSource=CIT, dataSubType=SecLegalAgreementParty
datahelper.SecLegalAgreementParty.indexes = agreementIdPartitionIdClientId
datahelper.SecLegalAgreementParty.index.agreementIdPartitionIdClientId.columns=agreementID, partitionID, clientID
datahelper.CITPricerOverrideByTrade.queryAttributes = type=DataProcessorHelper, contextType=REFERENCE, dataSource=CIT, dataSubType=PricerOverrideByTrade
datahelper.CITPricerOverrideByTrade.preload    = true
datahelper.CITCrisiDerivativePosition.queryAttributes = type=DataProcessorHelper, contextType=CALC, dataSource=CIT, dataSubType=Exposure, dataProcessorHelperType=result, CanonicalClassName=com.jpmorgan.gcrm.calc.crisi.deriv.common.data.result.CECrisiDerivativePosition
datahelper.CITCrisiDerivativePositionCalcMetricResult.queryAttributes = type=DataProcessorHelper,  dataSource=CIT, dataSubType=Exposure, dataProcessorHelperType=result, CanonicalClassName=com.jpmorgan.gcrm.calc.crisi.deriv.common.data.result.CECrisiDerivPsnCalcMetric
```

I just need to extract all properties with `datahelper.{anything}.queryAttributes`
Can we omit the properties with `CanonicalClassName=` in the same expression.
My Code is like:

```
for line in file:
    if re.match("^[datahelper.CIT]", line, False): 
        print line
```

Please assist.

Thanks

Comment: Is `{anything}` really anything? Shouldn't that be restricted to, for instance, alphanumerics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for line in file:
    if re.match("datahelper\.\w+\.queryAttributes", line): 
        print line
```

This regex matches lines that start with `datahelper.`, followed by one or more alphanumeric characters, followed by `.queryAttributes` (and any number of characters after that).

To further avoid those that contain `CanonicalClassName=` in the same line, you can add a lookahead assertion:

```
for line in file:
    if re.match("datahelper\.\w+\.queryAttributes(?!.*CanonicalClassName=)", line): 
        print line
```

Answer (score 2):

`^[datahelper.CIT]` matches one of the letters in that character group. That's not what you want.

Something like this would work:

```
for line in file:
    if re.match(r'datahelper\.(.*?)\.queryAttributes', line):
        print line
```

Or in compiled form:

```
matcher = re.compile(r'datahelper\.(.*?)\.queryAttributes')

for line in file:
    if matcher.match(line):
        print line
```

Comment: No need to use `^` with `re.match()`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I never knew that. Thanks.

Comment: @Blender : Can you please update your regex with my edited problem.